# Cloth simulation dosn't work (problem with properties)

Tags: cloth-simulation

A newbie.
I applied "All transforms" for a shirt, coat, body (neck), choose them as collision objects, but a scarf around (with also "all transforms") a neck doesn't simulate right.
I need any ideas for what cause that mistake in the simulation.
Thanks in advance

problem: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGoD3.jpg]

Comment: Hello Elationa, welcom to StackExchange. Please be aware of that people want to help you. They can help you as better as better you describe what you did. Best support you can get if you provide your  blend file. You can do this here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Have you tried to lower the Distance value for the Object Collision and Self Collision? The default value of 15 cm is often too high. Try 5 cm, 3 cm, or 1 cm. You could also try to define a Pin Group so that the scarf is fixed around the neck and only the ends are loose.

Comment: I've tried to decrease to 1 cm but it didn't work. I will try a Pin Group. However the ends were damaged during simulation and I also wanted to wrap it around the neck with simulation
This is the model without details
"[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=4sVXgZbB" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4sVXgZbB/)

Answer (score 1):

the problem solved - I significantly increased scale of the character for the simulation
thank you all